# getfloat returning 23.7999

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#define MAXBUF 1000
int buf[MAXBUF];
int buffered = 0;
int bufp = 0;

int getch()
{
    if(bufp > 0) {
       if(!--bufp)
          buffered = 0;

       return buf[bufp];
    }
    else {
       buffered = 0;
       return getchar();
    }

}

void ungetch(int c)
{
     buf[bufp++] = c;
     buffered = 1;
}

int getfloat(float *pn)
{
    int c, sign, sawsign;
    float power = 1.0;

    while(isspace(c=getch()))
         ;

    if(!isdigit(c) && c!= '+' && c!= '-' && c != '.') {
          ungetch(c);
          return 0;
    }

    sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;

    if(sawsign = (c == '-' || c == '+'))
       c = getch();

    if(c != '.' && !isdigit(c)) {
         ungetch(c);

         if(sawsign)
            ungetch((sign == -1) ? '-' : '+');

         return 0;
    }

    for(*pn = 0.0; isdigit(c); c = getch())
        *pn = 10.0 * *pn + (float)(c - '0');

    if(c == '.')
       while(isdigit(c = getch())) {
         *pn = 10.0 * *pn + (float)(c - '0');
          power *= 10.0;
       }

    *pn *= sign;
    *pn /= power;

    ungetch(c);
    return c;
}
```

It always returns 23.7999 when i enter 23.8, and i have no idea why. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers are represented in base 2, and base-2 floating-point values cannot represent every base-10 decimal value exactly. What you enter as `23.8` gets converted into its closest equivalent base-2 value, which is not exactly 23.8. When you print this approximate value out, it gets printed as `23.7999`.

You are also using `float`, which is the smallest floating-point type, and has only 24 bits of precision (roughly 7 decimal digits). If you switch to `double`, the amount of bits of precision more than doubles from `float`, so the difference between a decimal value such as 23.8 and its `double` representation is much smaller. This may allow a printing routine to perform the rounding better so that you see `23.8` with `double`. However, the actual value in the variable is still not exactly 23.8.

As general advice, unless you have a huge number of floating-point values (making memory usage your primary concern), it is best to use `double` whenever you need a floating-point type. You don't get rid of all odd behavior but you're going to see less of it than with `float`.

Answer (score 3):

Because certain floating point numbers are [inherently inaccurate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: if you want 23.8, use a different datatype, like integers representing tenths or many languages have a Decimal type.  I think most banks use integers representing thousandths of dollars.

Comment: I tried using double as an argument and it works fine now. Why can it work fine with double then?

Comment: Rounding/conversion oddities.  Converting decimal->binary(converting to float/double)->decimal(printing out the value of the float/double) gives two points of rounding.  Using a float vs using a double will change the rounding/induced error, same as if some calculation rounded decimal values to 10 places vs 20 places.

Answer (score 2):

23.8 can't be represented exactly given the limited accuracy of IEEE 754 floats.

Comment: It cannot be represented exactly in any binary floating point representation, even with infinite accuracy.  The value in binary is 0.1100 repeating.